# Apache Service Startup Issue in GitLab Pipeline

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I encountered a problem in my GitLab pipeline when running a container with an Apache service. It failed because Apache was not operational when the pipeline proceeded. I solved it by adding a 60-second sleep in the pipeline. Is there a way to resolve this without hardcoding the sleep?

I attempted to address it using a health check in the Dockerfile, but it seems to be the wrong approach. How do you handle such situations?

stage code :

```
test_job:
  stage: test
  image: docker:20.10.16
  services:
    - docker:20.10.16-dind
  tags:
    - shell
  script:
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker run -d -p 80:80 --env APP_ENV=$APP_ENV --env APP_DEBUG=$APP_DEBUG --name $CONTAINER_NAME $CONTAINER_IMAGE_NAME
    - sleep 60
    - curl http://localhost:80
    - docker stop $CONTAINER_NAME
    - docker container rm $CONTAINER_NAME
```

Part of dockerfile where I'm trying to do what is described :

```
CMD composer install && \
    chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/config/autogenerated && \
    chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/var && \
    yarn install && \
    yarn encore production && \
    apache2-foreground
    
HEALTHCHECK --interval=10s --timeout=10s --retries=12 \
  CMD curl -f http://localhost:80 || exit 1
```

Comment: Please add a "Minimal, Reproducible Example" of your pipeline which will help understand your situation better.

Comment: Building on what @Raghu said, can you provide your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file and the full job output log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to resolve this without hardcoding the sleep?

Typically, you pollingly wait until the server responds.

```
- while ! curl http://localhost:80; do sleep 1; done
```

You could code a little bit of bash to add a timeout, but I am super lazy and use `timeout`:

```
- timeout 60 bash -c 'while ! curl http://localhost:80; do sleep 1; done'
```

or, not to be inside quotes, with exported function:

```
- f() { while ! curl http://localhost:80; do sleep 1; done; }; export -f f; timeout 60 bash -c f
```

[Real life example from clickhouse](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/master/docker/server/entrypoint.sh#L132).